# How to set the spacing between RadSplitContainers in the RadDocking?

Tags: wpf, telerik

I would like to change style of `RadDocking` in my WPF Application. I have found solution how to change the `Padding` in the `RadDocking`, but any property or solution for removing or changing space width between `RadSplitContainer`. I can now only change the `Margin` of RadSplitContainer but I would to find some property or some style for it maybe it `ControlTemplate`.

[image: RadDocking and space width which I would to change]

Answer (score 1):

You can put each RadPane in its own RadPaneGroup. Then you can add margin to the RadPaneGroup. This will allow you to control the spacing in between each pane. It would look something like the below sample. I hope this helps answer your question!

```html
<RadDocking>
  <RadSplitContainer>
    <RadPaneGroup Margin="0,0,25,0">
      <RadPane/>
    </RadPaneGroup>
    <RadPaneGroup>
      <RadPane/>
    </RadPaneGroup>
  </RadSplitContainer>
</RadDocking>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help me